# OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError while trying to run chef-server

Tags: ubuntu-12.04, chef

Installed Chef server on my Ubuntu 12.04 server.

Following these [instructions](http://www.getchef.com/blog/2013/03/11/chef-11-server-up-and-running/)

Getting the following error

```
# chef-server-ctl test
The source :rubygems is deprecated because HTTP requests are insecure.
Please change your source to 'https://rubygems.org' if possible, or 'http://rubygems.org' if not.
Configuring logging...
Creating platform...
Configured URL: https://projects.anybots.com:443
Starting Pedant Run: 2014-06-04 13:06:09 UTC
setting up rspec config for #<Pedant::OpenSourcePlatform:0x00000002c1ec40>
Configuring RSpec for Open-Source Tests
 _______  _______  _______  _______  _______  ______   _______
|       ||       ||       ||       ||       ||      | |       |
|   _   ||    _  ||  _____||       ||   _   ||  _    ||    ___|
|  | |  ||   |_| || |_____ |       ||  | |  || | |   ||   |___
|  |_|  ||    ___||_____  ||      _||  |_|  || |_|   ||    ___|
|       ||   |     _____| ||     |_ |       ||       ||   |___
|_______||___|    |_______||_______||_______||______| |_______|

     _______  _______  ______   _______  __    _  _______
    |       ||       ||      | |   _   ||  |  | ||       |
    |    _  ||    ___||  _    ||  |_|  ||   |_| ||_     _|
    |   |_| ||   |___ | | |   ||       ||       |  |   |
    |    ___||    ___|| |_|   ||       ||  _    |  |   |
    |   |    |   |___ |       ||   _   || | |   |  |   |
    |___|    |_______||______| |__| |__||_|  |__|  |___|

                    "Accuracy Over Tact"

                  === Testing Environment ===
                 Config File: /var/opt/chef-server/chef-pedant/etc/pedant_config.rb
       HTTP Traffic Log File: /var/log/chef-server/chef-pedant/http-traffic.log

Running tests from the following directories:
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/spec/api
Run options:
  include {:focus=>true, :smoke=>true}
  exclude {:platform=>:multitenant, :cleanup=>true}
Creating client pedant_admin_client...
Exception during Pedant credentials setup
#<OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read server hello A>
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/core_ext/net_http.rb:59:in `connect'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/core_ext/net_http.rb:59:in `block in connect'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:55:in `timeout'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/timeout.rb:100:in `timeout'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/core_ext/net_http.rb:59:in `connect'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:756:in `do_start'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rest-client-ba0d12258b77/lib/restclient/request.rb:183:in `transmit'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rest-client-ba0d12258b77/lib/restclient/request.rb:69:in `execute'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rest-client-ba0d12258b77/lib/restclient/request.rb:36:in `execute'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/bundler/gems/rest-client-ba0d12258b77/lib/restclient.rb:73:in `post'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/request.rb:107:in `authenticated_request'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/request.rb:129:in `post'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/opensource/platform.rb:81:in `create_client'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/opensource/platform.rb:122:in `client_from_config'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/opensource/platform.rb:40:in `block in setup'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/opensource/platform.rb:35:in `each'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant/opensource/platform.rb:35:in `setup'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/chef-pedant/lib/pedant.rb:125:in `block (2 levels) in configure_rspec'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:23:in `instance_eval'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:23:in `run'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:72:in `block in run'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:72:in `each'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:72:in `run'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/hooks.rb:424:in `run_hook'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:27:in `block in run'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:34:in `report'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:25:in `run'
/opt/chef-server/embedded/service/gem/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.11.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
./bin/chef-pedant:29:in `<main>'

Finished in 0.2279 seconds
0 examples, 0 failures
root@projects:/opt/chef-server#
```

Comment: You should address the warning message about the insecure implementation used by rubygems.  The error is connected to your Pedant credentials, I would verify everything is configured, per your specific setup.

Comment: Yes I have been trying that actually. My problem is that I am not sure how. I did try to instal rubygems and update to the latest version, but that didn't help

Comment: Did it get rid of the warning at least?

Comment: No it didn't, so I know I am not doing it right. I just don't know where to change the source. I may need to rerun `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure`

Comment: `sudo chef-server-ctl reconfigure` didn't help

Comment: Restarted the machine (cloud server) and everything went into place (??)

Comment: Why did you end your last comment with a question mark?

Comment: cause I still don't know what fixed it and I am still having the :rubygem warning.